# Gmail keeps sending emails from local machine

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I developed a site with PHPMailer and used gmail smtp to send emails from my local machine.

My code:
`require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/classes/system.class.php';
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/helpers/send_email.helper.php';
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/modules/settings/classes/settings.class.php';

```
$sClass = new System();
$settingClass = new Settings();
$template = file_get_contents('../html/frontend/email_contact_form.html');

$site_email = $settingClass->get_setting_value('email_from_address');

$template_data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$template_data['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
$template_data['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$template_data['message'] = $_POST['message'];

$template = $sClass->merge_data($template, $template_data);

$result = send_email($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['name'], $site_email, 'Ruth Rudin', $_POST['subject'], $template);

echo '<p>Your message has been sent.</p>`
```

On the live server, I do not use gmail smtp.

My client keeps getting emails from root@localhost.

Could these be emails I tested and got stuck in the queue?

If so, where can I see this queue and delete these emails?

Very confused here.

Thank you

Comment: Please paste your code

Comment: and next time remember not to test with your client's e-mail

Comment: I added my code to the post.

Julio, thank you, for your suggestion, a good one.

Comment: @SigalZahavi - you're using `send_email` to do the work of sending your emails, but that function isn't in your question. I'd guess that you're not setting the `From: ` line in your email header, so emails are being sent with the default values.

Comment: @andrewsi, thank you, but send_mail is a function I created that uses PHPMailer to send the mail.
The form in question has google recaptcha on it, so fields can't be empty, yet the email received has empty fields in it. Sending it now from the live site, I can't submit the form without filling all the fields and the email received is fine. That's why I think there are still emails stuck somewhere from my testing.

Comment: @SigalZahavi - have you looked at the headers of the emails that are being received? There are lines in there that track the progress through mailservers, so you can see if they're new emails or have been stuck somewhere for a while.

Comment: @andrewsi, thank you, I will check that